# Downloading the visualization as screenshot and data in ECharts by Baidu

Tags: data-visualization, echarts

I've been learning how to use ECharts lately, and couldn't figure out how in [this example](https://www.echartsjs.com/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-animation-delay), they have buttons (like this [image: screenshot here]) on the top right that allow user to download the graph as a screenshot and see the background data.

In some other examples like [this](https://www.echartsjs.com/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple), there's no such button, so I'm assuming it's part of ECharts features.

Could anyone, familiar with ECharts, please help explain how to turn those options on? Thank you in advanced for your answers!

Answer (score 2):

Just by browsing around more in [these examples](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/index.html#chart-type-bar), I believe this is what turns on the 'Save As Image', 'Show Data' options ([an example usage](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=mix-zoom-on-value)).

```
toolbox: {
    show : true,
    feature : {
        mark : {show: true},
        dataView : {show: true, readOnly: false},
        magicType: {show: true, type: ['line', 'bar']},
        restore : {show: true},
        saveAsImage : {show: true}
    }
},
```

If anyone has more comprehensive explanation as to what features are available and how to use them, I'd love to learn more and accept it as an answer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This documentation list all the available toolbox features https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#toolbox.feature.

Comment: All the links on question and answer are outdated. Needs to update!